# Symbolism of the menorah and the two anointed ones in Zechariah 4

Tags: navi-prophets

I would have to put the entirety of Zechariah 4 here to give adequate context for this question.

In the passage, Zechariah has a vision of two olive trees that stand on either side of a menorah. Zechariah asks the angel twice what they are, and this is the response given:

> Then said he: ‘These are the two anointed ones, that stand by the Lord of the whole earth.’ -Zechariah 4:14, JPS translation.

This has always been a puzzling text for me:

- Who are these "anointed ones"?
  (I have seen claims that they are Joshua and Zarubbabel, such as this site [https://outorah.org/p/3646/]. This author makes this claim as if it were plain in the text, but it doesn't seem to be. Could there be another explanation?)
- What is the symbolism behind these two anointed ones supplying the menorah with oil?
- The menorah itself seems to be unique in its construction, with seven spouts on each of the seven lamps. What is the symbolism of this?